# Data Validation: How do I make my program issue an error until the correct input is selected?

Tags: python, validation

```
print "Welcome to aa47's Voice Mail Message Program!"
print "You are currently using a"+ " " + platform.system()+ " Operating System"
g = raw_input("What gender would you prefer Male or Female? (Please press m or f)")
```

## I believe i need to create a loop but i am unsure how

```
if g == "m":
    print "You have chosen the Gender Male"
elif g == "f":
    print "You have chosen the Gender Female"
else:
    print "You have entered an invalid choice"
    print "Program restarting"
    execfile ("my python project.py")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to wrap it in a loop

```
valid_gender = False
while not valid_gender:
    g = raw_input("What gender would you prefer Male or Female? (Please press m or f)")
    if g == "m":
        print "You have chosen the Gender Male"
        valid_gender=True
    elif g == "f":
        print "You have chosen the Gender Female"
        valid_gender = True
    else:
        print "You have entered an invalid choice"
```

Comment: It is more efficient to check positive value, like wait_answer = True \n while wait_answer:, etc.

Comment: You are right, I just find what I wrote more readable to me personally. Also, given this circumstance I don't think the overhead will matter to much. But it is worth noting that using the not is less efficient. I would say that going with what the programmer finds more readable is the best case in this situation as both are equally valid.

Comment: writing efficient code is a good habit in any case. You never know when you may get into situation when performance matters